# Is this known PerFieldPostingsFormat bug in Lucene 4.1 or is this user error

Tags: java, lucene

Is this a Lucene (4.1.0) bug or user error, Im assuming bug because user coe is just passing a search to Lucene, but I cant find anything in JIRA

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:342)
at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:273)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsReader.terms(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:215)
at org.apache.lucene.search.TermCollectingRewrite.collectTerms(TermCollectingRewrite.java:58)
at org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreAutoRewrite.rewrite(ConstantScoreAutoRewrite.java:95)
at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQuery$ConstantScoreAutoRewrite.rewrite(MultiTermQuery.java:220)
at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQuery.rewrite(MultiTermQuery.java:286)
at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.rewrite(BooleanQuery.java:429)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.rewrite(IndexSearcher.java:616)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.createNormalizedWeight(IndexSearcher.java:663)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
at org.musicbrainz.search.servlet.AbstractSearchServer.search(AbstractSearchServer.java:190)
at org.musicbrainz.search.servlet.AbstractSearchServer.search(AbstractSearchServer.java:172)
at org.musicbrainz.search.servlet.SearchServerServlet.doSearch(SearchServerServlet.java:616)
at org.musicbrainz.search.servlet.SearchServerServlet.doGet(SearchServerServlet.java:551)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
```

Comment: Can happens when user parses a query string where he has used / as a literal but not escaped as it needs to be to form a  regular expression, (Lucene now uses this to denotes regular expressions, but didn't use to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by user constructing an invalid query which doesn't taken into account that '/' is now used for regular expressions, this query should be rejected by MultiFieldQueryParser.parse() but does not, and this leads to the NullPointerException when actually try to run the query

Raised issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6347